# Derivative of the Dirac delta function. The Fourier transform of this function is the a-th derivative of the Dirac delta function. How to interprete?

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

Evaluating this integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{a} e^{-i(k-k')x}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}(-i)^a\delta^{(a)}(k-k')$$
I got this result that lead to the definition of $$\delta^{(a)}(k-k')=\sqrt{2\pi}(i)^a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{a} e^{-i(k-k')x}dx$$
Obtained applying this property and iterating
$$\int f(k)\delta^{(a)}(k-k')dk=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}\delta^{(a-1)}(k-k') $$
What's the difference between the cases $a\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$)
How could i interprete this result? How is defined the derivative of the Dirac delta function?

Comment: One way to think about $\delta'(x)$ is $$\int\limits_{-\epsilon }^{\epsilon } \delta'(x)\, f(x) \, dx=-f'(0)\,,\quad\epsilon>0$$ which is analogous to $$\int\limits_{-\epsilon }^{\epsilon } \delta(x)\, f(x) \, dx=f(0)\,,\quad\epsilon>0.$$ More generally one has $$\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \delta^{(n)}(x)\, f(x)\, dx=(-1)^n\, f^{(n)}(0)\,,\quad\epsilon>0\land n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n\ge 0.$$ I'm not sure how fractional derivatives are handled.

Answer (score 1):

The $\delta$ distribution is defined by
$$
\langle \delta, \phi \rangle = \phi(0)
$$
or using integral notation,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = \phi(0)
$$
for every $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$

The derivative $\delta'$ is defined by
$$
\langle \delta', \phi \rangle = -\langle\delta, \phi'\rangle = -\phi'(0).
$$

For higher order derivatives we have
$$
\langle \delta^{(k)}, \phi \rangle = (-1)^k \langle \delta, \phi^{(k)}\rangle
= (-1)^k \phi^{(k)}(0).
$$